# Can i invoke binarySearch method without implementing comparator/comparable?

Tags: java, collections

Is it required to implement comparator or comparable if i want to invoke binarySearch() method to perform Search operation?I
I am facing exception when try to invoke binarySearch() method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class Student implements{
private int id;
private String name;

public Student(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Student() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

}
public class CollectionSearchDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(new Student(3, "ouier"));
    list.add(new Student(2, "fdgds"));
    list.add(new Student(7, "kiluf"));
    list.add(new Student(1, "6trfd"));
    list.add(new Student(8, "hjgas"));
    list.add(new Student(5, "ewwew"));

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {

            return arg0.getId() - arg1.getId();
        }
    });

    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Student student = (Student) iterator.next();
        System.out.print(student.getId()+":"+student.getName()+" ");
    }

    System.out.println("I want to do searching ");
    System.out.println("\n2 is at:"+Collections.binarySearch(list, 2, new Student()));
            // facing exception when i invoke binarySearch method.
}
}
```

An exception occurs when i try to search "new Student()" or "CollectionSearchDemo" as an argument.
I have no idea what should i pass as an argument in binraySearch method.

Please help me

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to use `Collections.binarySearch`. The first with just a list of elements and a key, but these elements must implement `Comparable`. The second way with the key and a comparator. If you don't want `Student` to implement `Comparable`, you have to use this one.

So you have to write something like :

```
 Collections.binarySearch(list, studentToBeFound, comparator);
```

with `studentToBeFound` being a `Student` instance and the comparator being a `Comparator<Student>` like the one you used in `Collection.sort()`.

Just reuse your previous Comparator that compare with `Id`:

```
private static final class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {

    return arg0.getId() - arg1.getId();
  }
}
```

Then, if you want to find the student with Id equal to 2:

```
Student studentToBeFound = new Student(2, "dummy string");
```

And use them with binarySearch:

```
int indexInList = Collections.binarySearch(list, studentToBeFound, new StudentComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of binarySearch method must be a Comparator, the exception is thrown because your class Student doesn't implement Comparator interface.

`binarySearch(List list, Object key, Comparator c)`

Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

The parameter c must be an instance of a class that implements Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes - the binary search does not know whether the `Student` you are searching for is 'bigger' or 'smaller' then each in the list and therefore cannot search.
You want to implement comparable on the `Student` using the code you already have in the comparator:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
//stuff
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Student o) {
  return getId() - o.getId();
 }
}
```

Then your code with look something like this:

```
final Set<Student> set = new TreeSet<Student>();
//add students etc...
final Student found = Collections.binarySearch(set, studentToLookFor);
```

Answer (score 1):

A list cannot be sorted if we do not know how it is to be ordered. The binary search algorithm requires that the list be sorted and it uses the ordering of the list to search the list bu cutting the search field in half with each iteration. But the notion of whether Student x is in the first half of the list or the second half of the list requires that we know how this list is sorted.

Option 1: `public class Student implements Comparable<Student>`

Option 2: Write a Comparator class for Students.

`public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student>`

Answer (score 1):

Binary Search **needs** a sorted list.

This kind of searching is based in partitions:

1. Taking the middle element and comparing it to the reference.
2. The binary search continues in the first half of the collection if the comparation states that your reference is "lower" or, it continues in the second half if it is "higher".
3. When the comparation returns `0`, the element was found.

With this in mind, it is actually a requirement that the list is sorted. You can do it in different ways:

- Sorting it with the aid of a `Comparator` and then invoking `binarySerarch`
- Sorting a collection of elements that implement the `Comparable` interface and then invoking `binarySearch`
- Leaving the sorting to the `binarySearch` method if you provide the required `Comparator`.